# Is there a way to get Teamcity to interpret Specta test output?

Tags: teamcity, specta

I am using [Specta](https://github.com/specta/specta) testing framework for testing an ios mobile application. [Teamcity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity) does not do a very good job at parsing the test output and listing which tests failed (like it does with rspec). Is there a way to get Teamcity to play nicely with Specta?

Comment: Of course there is. Write a plugin...

Comment: Before you do that, can you fill in the specta wiki entry associated with the tag you used? I can't even discover what specta is right now.

Answer (score 0):

I never used Teamcity, but I've done integrations of Specta run from the terminal with CI systems. Something that helped me is [xcpretty](https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty) which allows you to have the test results output formatted in several styles.